SharePoint Library Thumbnail image not updating
I have created SharePoint Document library named "Software development" following this guide,and it shows as Template in Office 365, the problem is Thumbnail,it shows this "Folder" icon, instead the one i specified.
Set-SPOOrgAssetsLibrary -LibraryUrl https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/templates/Software%20Development -ThumbnailUrl https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/templates/SiteAssets/icon.png

Tried this version also:
Set-SPOOrgAssetsLibrary -LibraryUrl "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/templates/Software Development" -ThumbnailUrl https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/templates/SiteAssets/icon.png

Properties shows correct image
DisplayName  : Software Development
LibraryUrl   : /sites/templates/Software Development
OrgAssetType : OfficeTemplateLibrary
ThumbnailUrl : SiteAssets/icon.png

Thumbnail URL is correct and it's showing when visit URL
Have been waiting for 5 days and image is not changing.

